# Build URL to data file download with link to folder

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a web application that triggers actions at the server side which result in the generation of data files.

The so generated data files are stored within a folder at drive different from the one where the Web application is.

What I tried so far is to create a shortcut (Windows Server) next to the `Index.html`, where the shortcut points to the folder at the second drive.

This solution does not appear to work:

1. If I copy the data file to the same folder where the `Index.html` file is and enter navigate to the URL `httm://127.0.0.1:324324/Data_File.xlsx` I get the file downloaded.
2. If I enter `httm://127.0.0.1:324324/MyShortcut/Data_File.xlsx` (where `MyShortcut` points to a folder in drive D) the attempt fails.

How can I achieve this?

The need to access files in the different drive is essential.

Comment: I don't know which Web server you are using but I think you can create a virtual directory on IIS or an Alias folder for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server to serve that folder under different location. The only reason you are able to see your app and access that folder is cause server is set up to serve it ATM, not because you are making the right calls from the front or cause the front is asking nicely.

Don't know what Windows server version you are using and IIS version that goes on it, or are you even using IIS (you most probably do) but depending on what you use you need to do something in a lines of this:

[IIS7 config](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754437(v=ws.10).aspx)

What you probably wanna do is create virtual folder in IIS. Try looking into it, then if you fail ask a question with proper tags according where are you stuck.

I don't see how this is connected to front-end at all so front end tags wont get you far.

EDIT:

Oh, in that case get a second file server running for that folder? This should be the fastest way, use what you can from this list:  [list](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

Comment: Thank you Dante for your reply. I know that this can be done via configuration of the Server, but I'm currently using Brackets as the development environment which has its own server (which does not appear to support that). I thought that using a "shortcut" should be possible. The Windows Server I'm working on is 2012 (if this helps in any way). As to "connected to front end", you are right. The Server is to deliver the already built link/URL for the download to the front-end application.